# Meterpreter reverse http Timeout settings

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

When setting the timeouts for the reverse connection do I need to set them when creating the payload in msfvenom or just set them in the listener?

Comment: The listener is the HTTP server so the settings are made there

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just set them in the listener.